# Energy harvesting circuit output inquiry

Tags: low-power, energy, energy-harvesting

I am doing an energy harvesting circuit experiment (LTC3108 IC chip).
There was an example in the LTspice program.
I observed the current of Vout and it was 99nA as follows. The voltage was found to be about 5V.
Is this circuit a voltage-boosting circuit? Should the current increase in other ways?
[image]

[image]

Comment: That measurement probably represents leakage current through C5. You don't have a load on the output, so there's no real current flow. Put a resistor from Vout to ground and measure the current through it. It should be much higher.

Comment: @JRE I added a 50 ohm resistor to Vout and simulated it. But there is no current. Is this the right thing to add?

Comment: How are you measuring the current? I am not familiar with using this software (although I probably should start using it... alot of people do!). Have you put a measurement device in *series* with your output? Rather than in parallel?

Comment: 50 ohm is a lot when you're using expressions like "energy harvesting"

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is - the idea of voltage boost that most people don't understand is how much power (watt) the source can generate. For example you have energy harvested power source is 0.5 watt (5 volt x 0.1 amp) and you want to boost the voltage to 8 volt or 10 volt for example then the amp will go down to 0.0625 amp or 0.05 amp respectively but still generate 0.5 of power.

Which means if you boost voltage the current (amp) will decrease likewise if you boost the current(amp) the voltage will decrease. And the power it is generated still equal to the same. However this does not apply to the household electricity because the amp it can generate is huge and you can go up to 1000 volt and produce 12 amp, 24 amp etc depending on your circuit

Actually i did experiment on the LTC3108 before but not very efficient circuit due to the breadboard platform. If it is direct on the circuit board it would be much efficient. [Energy Harvesting LTC3108](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aNczz2JZcC8&t=8s)

Answer (score 1):

Use transformer impedance ratios to match load to source. Your X1 is 1:10k might be too high or f too low.

Define Zs(f) source then choose Z(f)load wiser.